# Show that a twice differentiable function has increasing first-order derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $\phi(x,y): \mathbf{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be a twice
>    differentiable function and $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x
>  \partial y}>0$. Show that if $t \ge s$ then $\frac{\partial \phi(x,
>  t)}{\partial x} \ge \frac{\partial \phi(x, s)}{\partial x}$.

My attempt:

First, I have a question regarding the symmetry of second-order partial derivatives. I know that Clairaut's theorem is one way to show the symmetry of second-order partial derivatives. But in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Sufficiency_of_twice-differentiability) section of wikipedia: it says that "*A weaker condition than the continuity of second partial derivatives (which is implied by the latter) which suffices to ensure symmetry is that all partial derivatives are themselves differentiable.*" Does this mean that if $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$ are both differentiable, then $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x}$?

If the above is true, then my proof is as follows:

Since $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x}$, let $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = g(x,y)$. Since $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y \partial x}>0$, we have $\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}>0$, meaning that $g$ is increasing with respect to $y$. So for $t \ge s$, we have $g(x, t) \ge g(x, s)$ or equivalently, $\frac{\partial \phi(x, t)}{\partial x} \ge \frac{\partial \phi(x, s)}{\partial x}$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Is $n=2?\,\,\,$

Comment: Sorry, yes, $n=2$. I have edited the question.